How to color only the chapter, section and subsection numbers in Table of Contents?
I would like to change the color of the chapter, section and subsection numbers in the table of contents. I am using the minimal code below. However, it only colors the first chapter number, but leaves black lower levels of numbering, see attached picture. How to color the entire section and subsection number?
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tocloft}


%%%change color in section numbers%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\textcolor{red}}%
\renewcommand{\cftsecpresnum}{\textcolor{red}}%
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecpresnum}{\textcolor{red}}%

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chap 1}
\section{Sec 1}
\subsection{Subsec 1}

\end{document}



\textcolor{red} expects to get some data as an argument. Since the number data is not presented as "data" it will just grab the first this it sees and the result is what you see here.

To elaborate on daleif's comment, you should replace each occurrence of \textcolor{red} in your original source code with \color{red}. This will result in the following output:


You cannot always expect that the macros is executed in a manner where they are given an argument. Here, say, \cftsecpresnum is used like this
...\cftsecpresnum #1...

where #1 is the numbering. So if #1 is 1.1 then \cftsecpresnum only grabs the first 1. You need it to run like
...\cftsecpresnum {#1}...

Here we are in luck as we can patch us to that result
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
% orignal code from tocloft
%\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{%
%  \hb@xt@\@tempdima{\@cftbsnum #1\@cftasnum\hfil}\@cftasnumb}
\xpatchcmd\numberline{\@cftbsnum #1}{\@cftbsnum {#1}}{}{\ERROR}
\makeatother

Here \@cftbsnum is internally set to \cftchappresnum, \cftsecpresnum...
